# code isn't working #selenium expert with python

Tags: python, dataframe, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver, browser-automation

I want to use Selenium to scrape information from the audible.com/search page. The csv file, however, shows an empty list. I'm going to share the code below. Can someone identify the original cause of the issue?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pandas as pd


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get('https://www.audible.com/search')
driver.maximize_window()

container = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'adbl-impression-container ')
products = container.find_elements(By.XPATH, './li')

book_title = []
book_author = []
book_length = []

for product in products:
    book_title.append(product.find_element(By.XPATH, './/h3[contains(@class, "bc-heading")]').text)
    book_author.append(product.find_element(By.XPATH, './/li[contains(@class, "authorLabel")]').text)
    book_length.append(product.find_element(By.XPATH, './/li[contains(@class, "runtimeLabel")]').text)

driver.quit()
df = pd.DataFrame({'title': book_title, 'Author': book_author, 'Length': book_length})
df.to_csv('books_amazon.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the locators you provided above were correct, try using below code with updated locators

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get('https://www.audible.com/search')
driver.maximize_window()

book_title = []
book_author = []
book_length = []
products = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@id,'product-list')]")
for product in products:
    book_title.append(product.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                           './/li[contains(@class,"bc-list-item")][1]//h2[contains(@class,"bc-heading")]').get_attribute(
        "textContent").strip())
    book_author.append(
        product.find_element(By.XPATH, './/li[@class="bc-list-item" and contains(text(),"Written by:")]').get_attribute(
            "textContent").replace("\n", "").replace("Written by:", "").strip())

    try:
        book_length.append(
            product.find_element(By.XPATH, './/li[@class="bc-list-item" and contains(text(),"Length")]').get_attribute(
                "textContent").strip())
    except NoSuchElementException:
        # Adding Blank
        book_length.append("")
        print("Length is not added")

driver.quit()
df = pd.DataFrame({'title': book_title, 'Author': book_author, 'Length': book_length})
df.to_csv('books_amazon.csv', index=False)
```

outputs csv like below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) solution. `pip install seleniumbase pandas`, and run with `python`:

```py
from seleniumbase import SB
import pandas as pd

with SB() as sb:
    sb.open("https://www.audible.com/search")
    sb.sleep(0.5)
    sb.scroll_to_bottom()
    sb.sleep(0.5)
    sb.scroll_to_top()
    sb.sleep(0.5)

    titles = sb.find_elements('h3 a[href^="/pd/"]')
    authors = sb.find_elements('span a[href^="/author/"]')
    lengths = sb.find_elements('li .bc-text:contains("Length:")')

    book_title = [title.text for title in titles]
    book_author = [author.text for author in authors]
    book_length = [length.text for length in lengths]

df = pd.DataFrame({'title': book_title, 'Author': book_author, 'Length': book_length})
df.to_csv('books_amazon.csv', index=False)
```

The output is `books_amazon.csv`.

[image]

Comment: wow sb looks good. I never see anything like that.